# Multiple embedded stream with sorting

Tags: api, twitch

I want to embed on my website multiple streams from twitch and sort them according to status (online,offline).

```
<script src= "https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div id="SamplePlayerDivID"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var options = {
    width: 854,
    height: 480,
    autoplay:true,
    channel: "channelTest1",
};
  var options2 = {
    width: 854,
    height: 480,
    autoplay:true,
    channel: "channelTest2",
};
  var player = new Twitch.Player("SamplePlayerDivID", options);
  var player2 = new Twitch.Player("SamplePlayerDivID2", options2);
  player.setVolume(0.5);
</script>
```

Is this correct way , and is it possible to solve like this?